# google.script.run.doSomthing() isn't working?

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

The simplest web app code is NOT working.  The code was copied as below from https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication.

The symptom is Logger.log did NOT log the output in the Executions (the history of executions of deployments).  It seems the function doSomething() was NOT invoked, implying that google.script.run was NOT able to call the user-defined function doSomething, as indicated by a few checks.

The new Apps Script editor was used.

File Code.gs:

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index');
}

function doSomething() {
  Logger.log('I was called!');
}
```

File Index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script>
      google.script.run.doSomething();
    </script>
  </head>
</html>
```

File appsscript.json:

```
{
   "timeZone": "America/Los_Angeles",
   "dependencies": {},
   "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
   "runtimeVersion": "V8",
   "webapp": {
      "executeAs": "USER_DEPLOYING",
      "access": "MYSELF"
   }
}
```

Comment: In your situation, is this information useful? https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script#logs-in-web-apps-for-google-apps-script From a table in this post, it is considered that the reason for your current issue is due to "Without access token" and "Without linking GCP". If I misunderstood your situation, I apologize.

Comment: Try moving the script block to the body

Answer (score 0):

Logs are known to not log properly, when using a webapp. The issue is reported [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/134374008). Consider adding a +1 (on the top right) for Google developers to prioritize the  issue.

[Switching GCP](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects#switching_to_a_different_standard_gcp_project) should enable logging.